# Count no of occurences of elements in single row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I got a requirement like i need to find number of occurences of particular value in a single row of an oracle table.

Say my source table looks likes this,

```
ID   score1   score2   score3   score4 score5
---------------------------------------------
aa    -1       65       -1       -1      82
bb    -1       65       99       14      82
```

I need a query which will return the results like,

```
ID   score1   score2   score3   score4 score5  count ( count of -1 occurences)
------------------------------------------------------
aa    -1       65       -1       -1      82     3
bb    -1       65       99       14      82     1
```

And the version of oracle i'm using is Oracle 10g (so using PIVOT options ruled out).can anyone help me out solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either CASE or DECODE statement.

```
select table_name.*,
       case score1 when -1 then 1 else 0 end +
       case score2 when -1 then 1 else 0 end +
       case score3 when -1 then 1 else 0 end +
       case score4 when -1 then 1 else 0 end +
       case score5 when -1 then 1 else 0 end
        as score_count
  from table_name;
```

Sample [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/17428).

Comment: Tons of Thanks Ramblin !!.It works great for me.I tried with DECODE but CASE command make it simple. Also thanks a lot for your sql fiddle demo..